# Loop through single column of Userform

Tags: vba, userform

I've worked with userforms in VBA a bit and know some of the tricks for looping through all controls. However, I'm running into issues with this one, and need a way to read the values of the line and reason columns into arrays based upon the values of  **"Area"**  and  **"Shift"**. The possible values for these two columns are in the picture. 

Basically what I need is something like

```
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If somectl.Value = "Kitting" And otherctl.Value = "1" Then
        ReDim Preserve somearray(i)
        somearray(i) = ctl.Value
    End If
Next ctl
```

[image]

Comment: The problem here is that this form is (hopefully) actually a "Continuous Form" and each record contains controls with the same name.  I say "hopefully" because if your table is set up so that every control name in that picture is unique, you need to take a database design class.  Can you do this with a query, or even VBA if absolutely necessary?

Comment: @JohnnyBones Every column has a unique name. Like in the "area" column the names are **areadd1, areaadd2** and so forth. And no, I cant use a query.

Comment: When you say "need a way to read the values of the line and reason columns into arrays based upon the values of 'Area' and 'Shift'", can you expand on that a bit?  I'm not sure what is going into the array.  Are you only looking to put the Line and Reason fields into the array when Area = "Kitting" and Shift = "1"?

Comment: @JohnnyBones Basically I want to create 6 arrays for every combination of "Area" and "Shift." So one for Kitting Shift 1, another for Kitting Shift2, one for Delivery Shift 1 and so forth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've manage to standardized your naming, you can do it like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim areaCB As MSForms.ComboBox
    Dim shiftCB As MSForms.ComboBox
    Dim reasonCB  As MSForms.ComboBox
    Dim somearray

    For i = 1 To 3 ' 3 or more depending on how may you have in your form
        Set areaCB = Me.Controls("areadd" & i)
        Set shiftCB = Me.Controls("shiftdd" & i)
        Set reasonCB = Me.Controls("reasondd" & i)

        If areaCB.Value = "Kitting" _
        And shiftCB.Value = "1" Then
            If IsArray(somearray) Then
                ReDim Preserve somearray(UBound(somearray) + 1)
                somearray(UBound(somearray)) = reasonCB.Value
            Else
                somearray = Array(reasonCB.Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So for example in *areadd1*, **1** is the row number.
Correspondingly, the *ComboBox* next to it to the right is *shiftdd1* and so on.
This is just to give you idea. Modify it to suit your needs.